# Open Office Document from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: uwp, azure-blob-storage

by developing a UWP app I've an Azure Blob Storage containing an Office Document.
I'm exploring the possibility for that document of being open multiple times on different devices so that users can work in real time on it.
Does someone know it is possible?

Comment: Do you want to openapp and edit office document in uwp app?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your question. I want to launch Office from my uwp app so that the document can be edited in real time by different user on different devices at the same time.